# Is a certain mapping in the set of real sequences a norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We define mapping $d((x_n)):= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|x_n|}{n}$.

Is this mapping a norm in the space of real sequences ?

Comment: It's not a mapping unless you tell us what the domain is.

Comment: Evidently not: take sequence $x_n=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the fact that it's sometimes infinite, yes. It's absolutely homogeneous, is zero only for the zero sequence, and $d(x+y)\leq d(x)+d(y)$ as long as $d(x)$ and $d(y)$ are well defined.

In fact, $\sum a_n |x_n|$ is a "norm" for any non-negative (and not all zero) sequence $a_n$, and the set of real (or complex, for that matter) sequences on which the "norm" is finite (and is thus an actual norm) is a vector space.

Comment: Usually, finiteness is required for something to be called a norm.